# Will a Spanish visa issued to an Indian citizen with an incorrect date of birth cause me problems?

Tags: visas, spain, emiri-citizens

I am UAE resident but Indian citizen I have already travel to Spain but that time there was a bit of a mistake in my passport which I didn't notice that time.  That mistake was with my date of birth - my real date of birth is 31/03/93 but by mistake my country embassy made a mistake and wrote 21/03/93 which is now clear. But will this issue be a great issue or what should I do?

Comment: Has the mistake been fixed on your passport? Does the visa show the wrong DOB?

Comment: Yes mistake is cleared in my passport

Comment: I didn't apply for visa yet but previously I have gone there with mistaken passport

Answer (score 1):

**This should be fine.**

If your passport has the wrong date of birth, then as far as Spain is considered, that *is* your official date of birth.  So use the "wrong" date of birth for all associated travel documentation (visa, tickets, etc), and you will not have any problems.  The passport is the only piece of ID you really need for overseas travel, so there's no chance of them seeing any other birth date for you.

The only hypothetical situation I could see this causing problems is *if* you're renting a car, *and* your driver's license has a different DOB, *and* the rental agency notices the difference, *and* is not satisfied by your explanation.  That's four ifs in a row, and even if it does happen, you can just try another agency.

Also, in the future, if you renew your passport and get the date fixed, and you apply for a new visa and are asked about previously granted visas, it would be wise to attach a note saying that previous visa X was granted for passport number Y, which due to a clerical error had the wrong date of birth Z.  Otherwise they may have trouble finding your old visa, and the difference in dates may raise flags if they do match it.

Comment: From the OP and comments, it sounds like this already happened - he has renewed his passport AND has had it corrected, but is worried about Spain noticing that he's changed. So renting a car won't be a problem, but the immigration might query the change, is his concern?

Comment: ? Have I missed something (see comment above)?

Comment: It's unclear what the OP means by "mistake is cleared in my passport", and it's difficult to answer this without clarification.  Usually countries never edit passport vitals though, they'd just issue a new passport if there's a mistake.

Comment: Well since it's in response to 'Has the mistake been fixed in your passport" I think it's probably fair to assume it means it's been fixed through reissue.